# how can we wire up cluster based softwares using chef?

Tags: python, automation, chef-infra, orchestration

As part of a platform setup orchestration we are using our python package to install various software packages on a cluster of machines in cloud.

We have the following scenario:

1. out of many softwares, one of our software is Ambari(helps in managing hadoop platform).
2. it works as follows - 'n' number of cluster machines reporting to 1 ambari-server.
3. for each cluster machine to do reporting, we have to install ambari-agent on each of cluster machine and modify its properties file with the ambari server it is suppposed to report and start ambari-agent.

what are we able to do--
we were successful in installing ambari server and ambari agents seperately in our cluster machines with the help of seperate chef cookbooks.

what we are not able to do--
how can we modify each machine's ambari-agent properties file so that it is pointing to our ambari server IP. in general what is an elegant way to wire up cluster based softwares as part of chef orchestration?

NB:. ambari-server is created on fly and hence its IP is obtained during run time.

Is it possible? are there any alternatives to above problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scenario for [Chef-server](https://docs.chef.io) and [search](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html).

You will have to change your recipe that installs ambari agent to obtain IP of ambari server dynamically.

First you run recipes that configure your ambari server. When Chef has successfully run there it populates some information about the node to Chef-server, including recipes and roles that were applied to that particular node. You can go to chef-server and check the node attributes, particularly "recipes" attribute.

Now change your ambari agent recipe. I don't know how exactly agent's configuration file looks like but we are interested only in one line, where the IP of the master server is set.

Create a template of the configuration file and add it to the cookbook. Replace the harcoded master IP value with `<%= @master_ip %>`

Change the ambari agent recipe so that it set's this value correctly:

```
# search for the server node. I expect server node was configured with
# ambari::server recipe. If not, change it to the appropriate value and
# don't fortget to escape colons.
ambari_server_node = search( :node, 'recipes:ambari\:\:server' )

# now create the configuration file on ambari agent node from 
# the previously created template and pass the value for the @master_ip
# variable
template '/right/path/on/target/node/config.file' do
  [...]
  variables( :master_ip => ambari_server_node['ipaddress'] )
end
```

Comment: answer appears very relevant and addresses our use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a chef server, you can do a search for the node that runs the ambari-server recipe.  Then you use the IP of that machine.  Alternately, you can use a DNS name for the ambari-server, and then update you DNS entry to point to the new server when it is available.

Other options include using confd with etcd, or using consul.  Each would allow you to update your config post-chef with the ip of the server.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a perfect use case for [Consul](https://www.consul.io/).

> Flexible key/value store for dynamic configuration, feature flagging,
>   coordination, leader election and more. Long poll for near-instant
>   notification of configuration changes.

We've been starting to use it to solve an issue that sounds very similar to yours. Historically any sort of config was handled by a large Python codebase with tons of Chef thrown in. We've been working on replacing some portions of it with Consul.

The thing that really impressed me was seeing how quickly information sent through the cluster bubbles up to visibility. I can see machines provision and come online way before the cloud service's control panel does thanks to Consuls healthchecks.

It does a lot more than just acting as a key/value store. It can also handle service discovery and perform any sort of regular healthcheck that you might currently be tracking through something like Sensu.

I highly recommend checking it out.

Hopefully that's sort of helpful. Good luck with the deployments!